# ajax request in laravel 5

Tags: php, ajax, laravel

im not sure how to do this in laravel. Im trying to do a simple ajax request to my controller. Then in my controller return the values that i sent through so i can console.log the data.

However im having a problem doing so.

Ajax Request:

```
$.ajaxSetup({
        headers: { 'X-CSRF-Token' : $('meta[name=_token]').attr('content') }
    });
    jQuery.ajax({
        url:'/group/create',
        type: 'GET',
        data: {
            name: groupName,
            colour: "red"
        },
        success: function( data ){

            console.log(data);
        },
        error: function (xhr, b, c) {
            console.log("xhr=" + xhr + " b=" + b + " c=" + c);
        }
    });
```

Route:

```
Route::get('/group/create', ['middleware' => 'auth', 'uses' => 'GroupController@create']);
```

Controller:

```
public function create()
{

    $data = Request::all();

    return json_encode($data);
}
```

Now when i console.log the returned data it shows at the exact html for the page im on. Any ideas?

Comment: Not sure where, you're going wrong. Try to dd("Test if inside create"); in your controller's create method. and then check the console.

Comment: Can you try without the middleware and see if that gives a different result?

Comment: Are you getting any errors?

Answer (score 0):

Check on the browser console-network-lastprocess- preview, it could show you the error. 
 Also you can "console log" from the controller using Log::info('useful information') and it will show it to you at storage/logs/laravel.log

Answer (score 0):

You should use Laravel's JSON return: `return response()->json(['name' => 'Abigail', 'state' => 'CA']);`

But also what you're doing is actually calling a GET with data however it should be a POST in this case. If you have to provide data to a controller, it's a POST and you can just return the data that way.

So change your AJAX to be POST and then you can use the `Request::all()` to get all data, and return it via JSON.